# Can I use the 'Version Control path to custom assemblies" directory for any dlls?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

We are just setting up a Build Controller at work for our projects. Our projects depend on the DLLs from another application that is installed on the end-user's machine. I don't want to install that application on the build server unless I have to. To that end, I have tried placing the DLLs that I need into the custom assemblies folder, but MSBuild is unable to locate them from there.

Can I use the custom assemblies folder for any DLLs that my project needs, or is it only for DLLs that the build process needs? (i.e. NUnit, StyleCop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only for dll's that the build server needs.

For your dependencies you should package them as NuGet packages and have your projects take a dependency on that instead. This will allow these dll's to be resolved on any machine even if they don't have the bits installed.

You can use a UNC path as your nuget repository or ProGet which is free.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 2):

To add some details to the above answer, custom assemblies folder was a feature introduced in TFS2010 to the Build infrastructure, that will automatically copy dlls checked into version control to the Build machines (controller/agent). This functionality was added so that the custom build process designers didn’t have to visit each and every build machine to deploy the custom activities.

**Now would all DLL's copied to the custom assemblies folder be deployed to the build machines - YES, but will all of them be instantiated/loaded to the memory to be used - NO. Only classes with the following attribute [BuildActivityAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.buildactivityattribute.aspx) will be loaded to the memory.**

If your custom build activity class is not marked with the BuildActivityAttribute then the build definition won't be able to detect it, in that case it will throw the below error:

```
"TF21509:An error occured while initializing a build definition \CustomBuildTasks\BuildName:Cannot create 
unknown type '{clr-namepace:NamespaceName,asembly=AssemblyName}Activityname'."
```

Or If your custom build activity uses a dependent assembly (reference) which is needed to run activities, they will not be loaded properly. If this is the case you will get “unknown type” errors on build definition initialization.

To work around this issue, add a fake CodeActivity to your dependent assembly with the following class scoped attribute:

```
[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildActivity(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.HostEnvironmentOption.All)] 
Public sealed class FakeActivity : CodeActivity
```

Finally this is the path, where the DLL's will be downloaded on the build machines:

TFS Build Agents

```
Windows XP, 2003
C:\Documents and Settings\[Build Service User]\Local Settings\Temp\BuildAgent\[Agent ID]
C:\Documentsand Settings\[Build Service User]\Local Settings\Temp\BuildController\[Controller ID]

Windows 7,2008,....
C:\Users\[Build Service User]\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildAgent
C:\Users\[Build Service User]\AppData\Local\Temp\BuildController
```

References:

[SOURCE 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/03/11/using-the-custom-assembly-path-to-deploy-custom-tfs-checkin-policies.aspx)

[SOURCE 2](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-7-How-is-the-custom-assembly-found.aspx)

[SOURCE 3](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx)

[SOURCE 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.buildactivityattribute.aspx)

[SOURCE 5](http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/72-running-nunit-tests-from-team-foundation-server-2012-continuous-integration-build)